# Identifiability and unbiasedness

Tags: unbiased-estimator, estimators, identifiability

How do you show that if my model parameter $\theta$ (scalar) is U-estimable (i.e. if there exists an unbiased estimator of $\theta)$, then $\theta$ is identifiable? This makes sense intuitively, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at a proof. Let $X$ represent the data, a random vector whose true distribution is given by the parametric cumulative density function $F(x;\theta)$. Let  $\theta$ be U-estimable. To show that $\theta$ is identifiable, we are going to show that if $F(x;\theta)=F(x;\tilde\theta)$ for some parameter values $\theta$ and $\tilde\theta$, then it's necessarily $\theta=\tilde\theta$.

Firstly, since $\theta$ is U-estimable, there must exists a statistic $T(X)$ such that 
$$\mathbb{E}(T(X))=\int T(x) dF(x;\theta)=\theta$$
for all possible values of $\theta$.

Now let $F(x;\theta)=F(x;\tilde\theta)$ for some parameter values $\theta$ and $\tilde\theta$. Then we find that 
$$ \theta=\int T(x) dF(x;\theta)= \mathbb{E}(T(X)) = \int T(x) dF(x;\tilde\theta) =\tilde\theta, $$
proving that $\theta=\tilde\theta$.
This show the identifiability of $\theta$.

*Edit - spelling.*